# Can I somehow put @depends annotation inside a test method?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I was wondering if it is possible to move the `@depends` annotation as a function call inside a test method. If it is: How? If it is not, why not?

```
<?php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class DependencyFailureTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testOne()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(false);
    }

    /**
     * @depends testOne
     */
    public function testTwo()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. `@depends` means that one depends on another one for its input. You can however just call the function you want like you normally would:

```
public function testTwo()
{
    $this->testOne();
}
```